# Nested objects in NSDictionary with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have a JSON document which contains objects with known schema in an object with unknown keys and I'll like to map that with RestKit. Let me explain this:

```
{
    "object":
    {
        "unknownKey1" : {"data1" : "...", "data2" : "..."},
        "unknownKey2" : {"data1" : "...", "data2" : "..."},
        "unknownKey3" : {"data1" : "...", "data2" : "..."}
    }
}
```

The setup of the object with key "object" is only known at runtime. The keys included in the object have random names. However, I know the exact schema of the objects stored at these unknown keys.

Now I would like to map the content of the object with key "object" to a NSDictionary as it provides easy access to the random keys. However, as the schema of the objects stored at these keys is known, I would like them to be mapped to custom objects.

So is there a possibility to map to a NSDictionary containing these objects? I haven't found a solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912731/restkit-dynamic-nested-mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKDynamicObjectMapping dynamicMapping];
mapping.objectMappingForDataBlock = ^(id data) {
    NSDictionary* object = [data objectForKey: @"object"];
    NSArray* keys = [object allKeys];

    RKObjectMapping* dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping objectMapping];
    //Use the keys to define mapping
    return dataMapping;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out JSONKit https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit to create a NSDictionary from your JSON document.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a JSON Structure like this:

```
{
  "blake": {        
    "email": "blake@restkit.org",        
    "favorite_animal": "Monkey"    
  },    
  "sarah": {
    "email": "sarah@restkit.org",   
    "favorite_animal": "Cat"
  }
}
```

You can map it like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] ];
mapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES;
[mapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"username"];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"(username).email": @"email",
    @"(username).favorite_animal": "favoriteAnimal"
}];
```

You can read more at [RestKit Documentation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#dynamic-object-mapping)