# how convert RKObjectMapping (Reskit) to json string?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following code:

```
NSString *url =     @"http://mysite.com"
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:url];
objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

NSString *token = @"Token is getting from rest API"
[[objectManager client] setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"token"];  

RKClient *client= [objectManager client];     
RKRequest * therequest = [client requestWithResourcePath:@"/create"]; 


[therequest setHTTPBodyString:@"{user:user}"]; //Here receive a JSON value
[therequest setMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];   
[therequest setDelegate:self];                               
[therequest send];
```

This code works fine... but I have a problem, I need to send to Rest API a JSON object (like String) and I have a RKObjectMapping with the values that should be sending to Rest Api.

It is possible convert a RKObjectMapping to JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it natively unless you write a JSON library yourself.  Otherwise, consider leveraging something like [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), it's easy to use and works well.

[Here's an example usage](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/jsonkit-tutorial-for-beginners-demonstrating-use-with-the-rotten-tomatoes-api/).

Comment: Yes, I did think it... but I would want to know if it is possible... RKObjectMapping to JSON or NSDictionary.. but thanks for you answer 
+1 :)

Comment: This question appears to address your problem, but in reverse.  Perhaps it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057141/nested-objects-in-nsdictionary-with-restkit