# Restkit v0.20 Dynamic mapping to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, restkit

In Restkit v0.10 a mapping to a NSDictionary could be done with the following code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12057398/871459

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKDynamicObjectMapping dynamicMapping];
mapping.objectMappingForDataBlock = ^(id data) {
    NSDictionary* object = [data objectForKey: @"object"];
    NSArray* keys = [object allKeys];

    RKObjectMapping* dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping objectMapping];
    //Use the keys to define mapping
    return dataMapping;
};
```

In v0.20 this isn't anymore possible. How can I implement the same on Restkit v0.20?

Answer (score 0):

In 0.20, they use [RKDynamicMapping](http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html#//api/name/objectMappingForRepresentation%3a) instead of RKDynamicObjectMapping. I've not tested yet, but the answer is probably here:

```
RKDynamicMapping* dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];    
[dynamicMapping setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock:RKObjectMapping *^(id data) {
    NSDictionary* object = [data objectForKey: @"object"];
    NSArray* keys = [object allKeys];

    RKObjectMapping* dataMapping = [RKObjectMapping objectMapping];
    //Use the keys to define mapping
    return dataMapping;
}];
```

Or take a look at [their tutorial for 0.20](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#dynamic-object-mapping):